# Is there a way to delete an entity by its EntityKey witout loading it?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Is there a way to delete an entity by its EntityKey witout loading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link Tamir has works, but it uses an approach that the Entity Framework team no longer recommends.

Check out [this tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx) which is closer to the right way to do it. And also covers the gotchas in more depth. (Dislaimer: I would say that I wrote the tip!)

Hope this helps

Alex

Program Manager Entity Framework Team.

Comment: I guess i qualify the 'out of luck' part, this fact that i have to provide parent PKs is really unncessarry it should be fixed, for my opinion it's just a bug.

Comment: Most people agree with you and that is why the next version of the EF (starting with Beta2) introduces something called FK associations: http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:
http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/Entity-Framework-Beta3-Deleting-without-fetching.aspx