# grdview_RowDeleting DataItem is Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, aspxgridview

I have bound my datagrid to a list. I am following Repository pattern and using EF v4.1. I need to delete the Entity on row_deleting event. This is the code:

```
    protected void grdBooks_RowDeleting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int bookId = (int)e.Keys[0];
        //grdBooks.Rows[e.RowIndex] //this item's dataItem is always null.
    }
```

As I am working with Entities, I need the actual Entity to pass it to my GenericRepository which will delete that entity. I did get the bookId but I don't want to do silly things like fetching the Entity from database using this bookId and then passing it to my delete method. Why is the DataItem always null and what can I do to get back my entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need fetch anything to delete it. Just create Entity with specified Id, Attach it and then call Remove.

```
Person user = new Person() { PersonId = Id };
db.Persons.Attach(person);
db.Persons.Remove(person);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I get exception If I do it the way you suggest. EntityKey is null so cannot attach object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007737/is-there-a-way-to-delete-an-entity-by-its-entitykey-witout-loading-it

Answer (score 2):

DataItem = null because when You databind data to gridview only once in Page_Load

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        grid.DataSource = GetDataSource();
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

data is stored in Viewstate. After You click delete You postback to server. Data is still present in Gridview's viewstate and not rebound.

You can delete the object if You have Id. You can do it in 3 different ways

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx
2. call context.ExecuteStoreCommand and just do the regular DELETE FROM -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx (2nd example)
3. create stored procedure on database, import it to model and the call it using context.ExecuteFunction()

Answer (score 0):

I am not suer whether I have understood your question right or not but I think you should try this

```
grdBooks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[index].Text;
```

Comment: @Thomas:- I want to get the entity from the row on which the delete button was pressed. Did you get it? Please let me know if you still didn't get it. I will write a full explanation of what is my problem in a better way.